# Remove Vim highlighting on double quotes

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have syntax highlighting enabled so that I can change my comment colors in Vim.  However, I don't want Vim to highlight something like this

```
"text here, including the speech marks get highlighted"
```

It's whenever I have " " that it highlights it.  I specifically want to change that behavior. How do I do that?

Comment: Could you tell us what is the file type of your buffer? What is the result of the `:set ft?` command?

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE. Most programming languages use quotation marks for strings. This is why it gets highlighted.